Non-overlapping subnets always exist?
Suppose a net $(\alpha_i)_{i\in I}$, where $I$ is a directed set with no maximal element and $X$ a topological space, has no duplicate values. That is, for $i\neq j\in I$, $\alpha_i\neq \alpha_j$. Is it always true we can find two cofinal subnets $(\alpha_\mu)_{\mu\in I_1}$ and $(\alpha_\lambda)_{\lambda\in I_2}$, where $I_1\cup I_2=I$ and $I_1\cap I_2=\emptyset$? If we have a sequence, we can always take the even terms and odd terms as two subsequences. But is something like this always possible for nets? Thanks.

Please give the precise definition of subnet. Does it include cofinality?

@PaulFrost Yes, it does. Sorry I'll update.

A somewhat boring counterexample: if $I$ has a maximal element, then any subnet is forced to contain $\alpha_{\max(I)}$.

@DavidGao Thanks. I'll update and avoid that situation.

Yes, this is true. Consider the collection $M$ of all $(I_1, I_2)$, disjoint subsets of $I$ s.t. $I_1$ and $I_2$ dominate each other, i.e., for any $i \in I_2$, there exists $j \in I_1$ s.t. $j > i$ and similarly for any $i \in I_1$, there exists $j \in I_2$ s.t. $j > i$. $M$ is nonempty as $(\varnothing, \varnothing) \in M$. Let $M$ be ordered by inclusion on both entries, i.e., $(I_1, I_2) \leq (J_1, J_2)$ iff both $I_1 \subseteq J_1$ and $I_2 \subseteq J_2$. It is not hard to verify that any chain in $M$ admits an upper bound. Thus, by Zorn’s lemma, $M$ has a maximal element $(I_1, I_2)$. I claim that they satisfy the desired conclusion.
By definition, $I_1 \cap I_2 = \varnothing$. Now, assume to the contrary that $I_1 \cup I_2 \neq I$. Then there exists $i \in I \setminus (I_1 \cup I_2)$. Since $I$ has no maximal element, we may pick a strictly increasing sequence $(i_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $i_0 = i$. There are two cases:

If $I_1 \cap \{i_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite, then one observe that $(I_1, I_2 \cup (\{i_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \setminus I_1)) \in M$. As $i_0 = i \notin I_2$, this contradicts the maximality of $(I_1, I_2)$. The situation is similar when $I_2 \cap \{i_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite;
If both $I_1 \cap \{i_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $I_2 \cap \{i_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are finite, then by removing finitely many terms, we may assume $I_1 \cap \{i_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} = I_2 \cap \{i_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \varnothing$. But then $(I_1 \cup \{i_n: n \, \text{is even}\}, I_2 \cup \{i_n: n \, \text{is odd}\}) \in M$, again contradicting the maximality of $(I_1, I_2)$.

Thus, we must have $I_1 \cup I_2 = I$. I claim that this is enough to ensure both $I_1$ and $I_2$ are cofinal subnets. Indeed, assume $i \in I_1$ and $j \in I$. Then there exists $k \in I$ s.t. $i \leq k$ and $j \leq k$. If $k \in I_1$, then the result is proved. Otherwise, we must have $k \in I_2$. But then by definition of $I_1$ and $I_2$, there exists $k’ \in I_1$ with $k’ \geq k$. So, $k’ \geq i$ and $k’ \geq j$. This shows $I_1$ is a cofinal subnet. The same argument shows $I_2$ is a cofinal subnet as well.

Thank you for the answer! However, I don't understand why $(\emptyset, \emptyset)\in M$, according to how $M$ is defined. Can you please elaborate? Is it due to some axiom?

@user760 $\varnothing$ is disjoint from itself. And since there is no element in $\varnothing$, the dominating condition is vacuously true.

But is it possible $(\varnothing, \varnothing)$ is the only element of $M$? Sorry I don't know too much about nets and directed sets, other than their definitions.

@user760 If it is the only element, then it is maximal. And the argument in the answer shows that any maximal $(I_1, I_2)$ must satisfy $I = I_1 \cup I_2$. But $I \neq \varnothing$.

@user760 It is also not hard to directly get another element of $M$. Because $I$ has no maximal element, you can choose a strictly increasing sequence. Then the set of even-numbered elements and the set of odd-numbered elements form a tuple that’s easily seen to be in $M$.

Oh! I just realized, if $I$ has no maximal element, then $M$ always contains more elements than $(\varnothing, \varnothing)$. Because we can always take an increasing subchain $(i_1< i_2< \cdots < i_n < \cdots)$ and partition it with even and odd terms, and these can be the $(I_1, I_2)$ in $M$.
